# Eclipse 4: Default commands

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I apologise for the very amateur question about E4 but I am a bit confused about a couple of things about RCP development using the new Eclipse 4 framework. I read in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#commands_defaults) that one can no longer use any default commands the way we could in 3.x especially for common things like Save, Save As... in the File menu. It says that in E4 we have to write our own commands. The reason I am confused is because the thing I liked about Eclipse previously is that a lot of things are already implemented and we can just extend that to our own needs. But it feels like now everything must be written from scratch.

That led me to considering reusing the command code already written for Eclipse Juno. I had the Live Editor open so I could see the list of commands etc but I don't really see any Handlers implemented for any of them. Then I used the Spy on Eclipse Juno and checked out some of the menu items and they all seem to point to Actions. That really confused me as I thought Juno was based on E4.

I could be completely wrong so I am sorry for asking such a silly question. I only just started using E4 and need to decide whether one of fairly young Eclipse 3.x projects should be migrated to 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

AfaIk, in Juno the compatibility layer translates the 3.x based implementation of the IDE into E4 concepts. This is also the reason why the reusable commands are not yet available.
If you have an 3.x based RCP it should also run using the compatibility layer (and you can reuse the commands mentioned in your question) if no incompatible APIs have been used.

Here is more information (also a tutorial from Lars Vogel): http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4CompatibilityLayer/article.html